# i can't Query the SYS.User_tables inside java native query

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g

i want to get all tables names for the current schema ( i have many schemas)
so i use the user_tables which a system view that contain table_name column . but when im trying to query it inside java i get this this exception

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00903: invalid table name

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("SELECT * from FROM SYS.USER_TABLES ");
 Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sb.toString());
List list = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Simply you don't have permission to read that table. How about: `"SELECT * from FROM USER_TABLES"`

Comment: i get the same error

Comment: Can you please try "SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = <User name>".

Answer (score 0):

You have 'from' twice:

```
"SELECT * from FROM SYS.USER_TABLES "
```

This is being parsed as the `from` being the keyword, the `FROM` being the (invalid) table name, and the `SYS.USER_TABLES` being a table alias (also invalid, but has already failed by then).

It should be:

```
"SELECT * FROM USER_TABLES"
```

You don't need the `SYS.` prefix as mentioned in a comment. And if you only want the table names you should only select that column, not all columns via `*`.

Comment: It's a typo that's causing the ORA-00903. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: So you haven't posted the code you are actually running? How are we supposed to help then?